# conditional class binding in list using props in vue js

Tags: vue.js

progressbar component receives props from parent component name activeStep that its value is active index of progressbar. my challenge is while rendering list of progressbar i want to set active class to li s that less than value of active step property or equal to value
how can i do that?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul class="progressbar">
      <li v-for="(progressbarCase,index) in progressbarCases" :key="progressbarCase.id">
        {{progressbarCase.title}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
<style lang="css">
  @import "../assets/stylesheet/progressbar.css";
</style>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['activeStep'],
  data () {
    return {
      progressbarCases: [
        {title: 'first'},
        {title: 'second'},
        {title: 'third'}
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want add `class` conditional, you can use `:class=""`. For example: `:class="true ? 'active' : 'disable'"`. with this,if condition is true: `class="active"` else `class="disable"`

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple, if you have more than one conditionnal class, you need to define the `:class` attribute as an object like this:

```
<li :class="{
    'a-conditional-class': true,
    'an-other-conditional-class-but-not-displayed': false,
}">
</li>
```

For your information, you can also couple conditional and unconditional classes !
And in one `:class` attribute, like this:

```
<li :class="[
    'an-unconditional-class',
    {
        'a-conditional-class': true,
        'an-other-conditional-class-but-not-displayed': false,
    }
]">
</li>
```

Have a look on the official documentation for more information about Class an style binding: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#ad